# C++: Segmentation fault while iterating over vector of pointers while push_back

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers, segmentation-fault

I want to iterate through a vector of pointers pointing on objects. While iterating, I have to push_back new pointers to the vector. Before the loop, the number of push_backs is unknown and there is no abort criterion, so that I can't use a while loop.

Here is an example using pointers on integers, that shows the same error as the version with objects: Segmentation fault (core dumped) after one iteration.

```
vector<int*> vec;
int a = 43;
vec.push_back(&a);

for (vector<int*>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    cout << *(*it) << " " << *it << endl;
    vec.push_back(&a);
}
```

The same Code but with integers works great.

```
vector <int>vec;
int a = 43;
vec.push_back (a);

for (vector < int >::iterator it = vec.begin (); it != vec.end (); ++it){
    cout << (*it) << " " << *it << endl;
    vec.push_back (a);    
}
```

Comment: `vec.push_back(&a);` pushes the address of a *local variable*, that is about to go out of scope (and will then be *invalid*), into the vector. That's unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my code, I wanted to use this loop to replace a recursion. Instead of integer pointers, I would pushback pointers on objects. I will switch to std::stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) invalidates the iterator when appending results in `size > capacity` so it reallocates and copies to the new space.

> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
>
> 2) value is moved into the new element.
>
> If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and
>   references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated.
>   Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated.

Plus as @Jesper pointed out you are storing a reference to a local variable in your `vector`:

```
int a = 43; 
vec.push_back(&a);
```

which  if went out of scope before your `vector` you will have dangling references.

Comment: You are ignoring the problem of putting the address of a local (soon to be dead) variable into the vector. Your answer would be better if it also addressed that.